# Selecting cells that contain events from an array VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to get my VBA code to tell me which cells in a column contain "events".  The spreadsheet has an event in cell(3,2) and then every 12th row after that (cell(15,2); cell(27,2); cell(39,2); and so on).

I created an array defines the event names and I want to select the cell that holds any of those values one by one.

```
Dim eventsArray(3) As String
eventsArray(0) = "W"
eventsArray(1) = "X"
eventsArray(2) = "Y"
eventsArray(3) = "Z"

Dim eventRow As Range

For i = 1 To maxRow 'my maxRow was already defined properly 
    eventRow = Cells(i, 2)
    If eventRow.Text = eventsArray Then
        eventRow = Cells(i + 1, 2)
    End If
MsgBox (eventRow)
Next i
```

I am certain this is super easy, nothing has been going right today.

Comment: is there a reason you use `.Text` instead of `.Value`? `.Text` is the displayed Text, not the cell value (for example "####" if the column is too narrow)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the Cell Value is an element of the array, you have to loop through the whole array and check each value against it, so something like this:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim eventsArray(3) As String
Dim arrayElem As Variant 'Variable for looping the Array(needs to be Variant)
eventsArray(0) = "W"
eventsArray(1) = "X"
eventsArray(2) = "Y"
eventsArray(3) = "Z"

Dim eventRow As Range

For i = 1 To maxRow

    Set eventRow = Cells(i, 2) 'Set current cell to the range variable

    For Each arrayElem In eventsArray 'Loop through the array

        If eventRow.Value = arrayElem Then 'If the Value matches with an item in the array

            MsgBox Cells(i + 1, 2).Address 'MsgBox with cell address
        End If
    Next arrayElem
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple, learning VBA on the fly is always fun.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to repeatedly test whether a value is in a set, a Scripting.Dictionary is likely going to give you the best performance:

```
'You need to add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.
Dim events As New Scripting.Dictionary
events.Add "W", vbNull
events.Add "X", vbNull
events.Add "Y", vbNull
events.Add "Z", vbNull

Dim eventRow As Range

For i = 1 To maxRow 'my maxRow was already defined properly
    eventRow = Cells(i, 2)
    If events.Exists(eventRow.Value) Then
        eventRow = Cells(i + 1, 2)
    End If
    MsgBox eventRow
Next i
```